# Scraping data via scrapy from table yields nothing

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am having issues extracting data from the table below.

https://tirewheelguide.com/sizes/perodua/myvi/2019/

I want to extract the sizes in this example & it would be the 175/65 SR14

```
<a style="text-decoration: underline;" href="https://tirewheelguide.com/tires/s/175-65-14/">175/65 SR14 </a>
```

Using scrapy shell function

```
response.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a[1]/text()').get()
```

yields nothing.

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why you are using `beautufulsoup` are you accepting answer in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your XPath

instead this:

```
response.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a[1]/text()').get()
```

use this:

```
response.xpath('//table[1]//td//a/text()').get()
```

Some website doesn't create tables in proper so in my XPath I pass `html/body/div` also there was a problem with tr. The website creates multiple tr in the same row and it causes a problem. If you use the XPath I posted, it will work fine.